# Uploading JSON file to Mongodb with pymongo on Kali Linux

Tags: python, linux, mongodb, pymongo

I am uploading the `Json` file to `MongoDB` but I am getting this error. I am using `Linux`.

> AttributeError: module 'pymongo' has no attribute 'MongoClient'

but I have already installed `pymongo`.

```
def Uploaddb():
    client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://username:password@devconnector.g6cxh.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
    db = client['Linux_Trace_db']
    linux_trace = db['linux_trace']
    
    with open('trace.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    
    linux_trace.insert_many(data)
    
    client.close()
 Uploaddb()
```

Comment: How does your `import` statement look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only `MongoClient`

```
client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://<Username>:<password>@devconnector.g6cxh.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority", serverSelectionTimeoutMS=10000);
```

Comment: it underlines the MongoClient and says `MongoClient is not defined `

Comment: @HassanTuri check out my [github](https://github.com/YuTingKung/fastapi/blob/main/main.py). it works for me.